How to split a Swift string into an array by spaces and special characters like question marks, exclamation points, and periods?
I'm trying to split a string in Swift into an array of words, but I want to separate the words not only by spaces but also by special characters like question marks (?), exclamation points (!), and periods (.).
For example, given the string "When is your birthday?", I want to get the following output:
["When", "is", "your", "birthday", "?"]

I can currently split the string by spaces using components(separatedBy: " "), but I'm not sure how to include special characters in the split as well.
How can I split the string by both spaces and punctuation? Ideally, I want the solution to work for question marks (?), exclamation points (!), and periods (.) but be flexible enough to add other characters in the future if needed.
Thanks for your help!

Can you explain what exactly is the logic here? You say "not only by spaces but also by special characters", and since the desired result doesn't include spaces, shouldn't it also not include special characters? Why are they treated differently? If you want to be consistent, the result should either be ["When", " ", "is", " ", "your", " ", "birthday", "?"] or ["When", "is", "your", "birthday"]. Also, what happens if there are multiple special characters in a row? Should they be separated or combined into a single element?

You can achieve this by using regular expressions (NSRegularExpression) to match both words and specified punctuation marks. This approach allows you to flexibly include any additional characters you might want to handle in the future.
import Foundation

func splitString(_ string: String, punctuation: String) -> [String] {
    // Escape special regex characters in the punctuation string
    let escapedPunctuation = punctuation.map { "\\\($0)" }.joined()
    // Construct the regex pattern to match words or any of the specified punctuation marks
    let pattern = "\\w+|[\(escapedPunctuation)]"

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
        let nsString = string as NSString
        // Find matches in the string based on the pattern
        let results = regex.matches(in: string, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
        // Extract the matched substrings
        let words = results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range) }
        return words
    } catch {
        print("Invalid regex pattern: \(error)")
        return []
    }
}

let inputString = "When is your birthday?"
let punctuationCharacters = "?!."

let words = splitString(inputString, punctuation: punctuationCharacters)
print(words) // Output: ["When", "is", "your", "birthday", "?"]


If you want to use components(separatedBy: " ") etc... try this simple approach,
replacing all desired markers by a blank space followed by (or prefixed by) the marker,
as shown in the example code
struct ContentView: View {
    let originalText = "When is your birthday?"
    let markers = ["?","!","."]

    @State private var results: [String] = []
    @State private var text = ""
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(originalText).foregroundStyle(.red)
            ForEach(results.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(results[index])
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            text = originalText
            text = markers.reduce(text) { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: $1, with: " " + $1) }
            text = markers.reduce(text) { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: $1, with: $1 + " " ) }
            results = text.components(separatedBy: " ").filter{!String($0).isEmpty}
            print("results: \(results)")
        }
    }
}

